# Mistake in using DOMPurify on the backend to sanitize form data?

Tags: forms, security, post, backend, dompurify

I was wondering if it was possible to use DOMPurify to sanitize user input on a form before it is saved to database. Here's what I've got in my routes.js folder for my form post:

```
.post('/questionForm', (req, res, next) =>{
        console.log(req.body);
        /*console.log(req.headers);*/
        const questions = new QuestionForm({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            price: req.body.price,
            seats: req.body.seats,
            body_style: req.body.body_style,
            personality: req.body.personality,
            activity: req.body.activity,
            driving: req.body.driving,
            priority: req.body.priority
        });
        var qClean = DOMPurify.sanitize(questions);
        //res.redirect(200, path)({
        //    res: "Message recieved. Check for a response later."
        //});
        qClean.save()
        .then(result => {
            //res.redirect(200, '/path')({
            //    //res: "Message recieved. Check for a response later."
            //});
            res.status(200).json({
                docs:[questions]
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

I also imported the package at the top of the page with

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
```

When I run the server and submit a post request, it throws a 500 error and claims that dompurify.sanitize is not a function. Am I using it in the wrong place, and/or is it even correct to use it in the back end at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but for others like me happening to run into this use case I found an npm package that seems well suited so far. It's called isomorphic-dompurify.

[isomorphic-dompurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify)

DOMPurify needs a DOM to interact with; usually supplied by the browser. Isomorphic-dompurify feeds DOMPurify another package, "jsdom", as a dependency that acts like a supplementary virtual DOM so DOMPurify knows how to sanitize your input server-side.

In the packages' own words "DOMPurify needs a DOM tree to base on, which is not available in Node by default. To work on the server side, we need a fake DOM to be created and supplied to DOMPurify. It means that DOMPurify initialization logic on server is not the same as on client".

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Seth Lyness's excellent answer --

If you'd rather not add another dependency, you can just use this code before you require DOMPurify. Basically what isometric-dompurify is doing is just creating a jsdom object and putting it in `global.window`.

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
const {window} = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>');
global.window = window;
```